# sqlite3.OperationalError: near "CASE": syntax error

Tags: python, database

I'm trying to insert data into sql table like this

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('Tags.db')
cur = conn.cursor()

input = open('word_freq_list.txt', 'r', encoding = 'UTF-8')


for word in input.read().split():
    p = morph.parse(word)[0]
    pos = p.tag.POS
    case = p.tag.case
    num = p.tag.number
    gender = p.tag.gender
    cur.execute(''' INSERT INTO Words_with_tags (POS, CASE, NUM, GENDER)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)''', (pos, case, num, gender))
    conn.commit()
```

But every I'm getting an error message:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "CASE": syntax error
```

I can't understand why: column names are placed in the right order, the names are right too.

Comment: Can you try ``INSERT INTO abc  (`POS`, `CASE`, `NUM`, `GENDER`)``? Case is a reserved keyword so might be throwing this error.

Comment: Yes, it still shows the same error.

Answer (score 1):

CASE is a [Reserved Word](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/coding-standards/list-of-sql-reserved-words), you can't use it as a column or variable name in your SQL query. Try using another column name instead of CASE.